# Is it possible to both catch browsers width and still adjust the content when browser is made smaller

Tags: html, css

Here is an example. If I, for example, set body to 70em and then adjust the browser width this rule

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px)
{
    body
    {      
        background : #B0E0E6 url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
}
```

is true when the width is between 481px and 1024px.
But when I have the `width:70em` given in body the content is not being adjusted when I make the width for the browser smaller.

If I now change a little and set the width in the body to be 80% now the content is automatically being smaller when the width of the browser is smaller.

It seems to me that it's not possible to both being able to catch when the browser is for example between 481px and 1024px and at the same time shall the content being able to be smaller when the browser width is made smaller.

So my question is if it's possible to both being able to catch when the width of the browser is between 481px and 1024px and at the same adjust the content automatically being adjusted when the width of the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the width to 70em. That's a fixed width (more or less considering it's based on font size). Within the media query you do not set the width anywhere. You just set the background. You would need to adjust the width of the object you want to resize within the media query. So if you have

```
body{
   width:70em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px)
{
    body
    {      
        background : #B0E0E6 url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
        width: 50em;
    }
}
```

That would resize the body based on the media query that you specify. Also, you may wish to look up CSS units to make sure you want to use em (because by your description, % may work for your needs): http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: But as I mentioned when I have given a width in the body as 70em for example the content that I have for example in a paragraph which is a p tag will not shrink when I make the browser smaller. So how do I fix that ?

Comment: Assuming I understand your issue, I have a question. Do you set a fixed size for the paragraph? If so, that would cause it not to resize when the body does.